# Can't see improvement requests when own draft is pending

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

It is not possible to see an improvement request for a topic on which one has an edit pending which is unrelated to the improvement request.

**EDIT:** Note that this seems to be because one cannot see a topic's current form when your own edit is pending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to see improvement requests in the edit window:

[image: Improvement request from the edit window]

(Of course that requires you to withdraw your draft from review.)

As of [Feburary](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343091/documentation-update-february-6th), you can also see improvement requests in the discussion tab:

[image: Improvement discussion]

If your change *does* handle an improvement request, the request is listed on the review page. It seems confusing to include requests that *aren't* handled. It will probably result in incorrect rejections.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing this as well.

### **Here is the notification for the improvement request:**

[image: Notification]

### When I click that link, this is what I see. No information about the improvement request is visible.

[image: What I see]

### If I open a private window (or log out), the improvement request is visible.

[image: What others see]