# Cannot flag if edits are pending

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation

When you have pending edits on a topic over at documentation, the flag icon is gone.

[image: lovingly rendered pictures of roosters ... er, normal behaviour]

---

That's how it looks normally. With edits pending, it looks like this:

[image: lovingly rendered picture of pending edits]

Furthermore, you cannot see the orange-ish box that describes the flags / improvement requests you or others have left.

Both are very briefly visible if you reload the page, so I guess they are hidden by some JavaScript trickery.

Related, but not quite duplicate: [Can't see improvement requests when own draft is pending](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329285/cant-see-improvement-requests-when-own-draft-is-pending)

Comment: I already added `.move-example, .delete-topic, .delete-example { display: initial !important; }` to User CSS because of stupid JS trickery. I guess adding `.improvement-request-link` to the selector list makes sense...

Answer (score 4):

That view is stripped down because the version with your edits isn't visible to anyone else. You can edit from it (and that amends your proposed change), but raising new flags doesn't necessarily make sense at that point.

Having said that, not being able to see what others are seeing *is* suboptimal. So starting with the next build, there will be a link to that when you're viewing the topic with your pending change applied:

> [image]

The "latest public" page will show remaining improvement requests and allow you to raise new ones, but it won't allow editing. There will be a link to take you back to your personal view with your pending-review changes applied to it:

> [image]

Comment: The thing is, I was going through a topic and making edits where I could and raising flags where I couldn't. I did not realise that an edit was for a full topic instead of a single example. (The fact is rather counter-intuitive.) (I'm veering off the topic here.) If an edit disabled the flag UI for just the single example that you edited, it would have been OK, but one disabled the UI for the whole page, which was a problem. Nevertheless, the implemented solution seems passable. Thank you for that.