# Alignment issue with Documentation - topic and discussion tabs are stacked

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-topics, firefox

There is an alignment issue in the Documentation Beta. The **topic** and **discussion** tabs are misaligned in the Firefox browser.

Firebox: `50.1.0`
OS: Windows: `8.1`

Link for the reference: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/15/getting-started-with-c-sharp-language#t=201702071514016331332

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Alignment issue]

Comment: Reproduced with both Firefox 51.0.1 on Windows 10, and Firefox ESR 45.6.0 on Debian Jessie. No issue in Chrome on Windows 10.

Comment: The same issue on Windows 7 (Firefox 51.0.1). No issue in Opera 42.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: This issue should be fixed now. Thanks for the report. Please ping me if you see any further issues.

Comment: In the `rev 2017.2.22.25205` this issue is fixed