# "Proposed change comment" is not on my proposed change

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, documentation, documentation-discussion

This is bugging me. My inbox is constantly filled with miscellaneous "proposed change comments" that I shouldn't be watching and often aren't even on proposed changes. There does, however, seem to be a pattern to these. All of these comments are on topics that I have edited in the past.

It would be annoying to have to unwatch all 700+ topics that I have edited individually. Can someone look into this?

Comment: Yup, anything you are an editor on you are auto-watching now.

Comment: As mentioned in the [latest omnibus feature update](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343091/documentation-update-february-6th), what you're watching can (finally) be managed centrally here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation&sort=watching

Comment: +1 There should be a way to unsubscribe from all notifications for  documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Making a non-trivial (potentially rep earning) edit to a topic now subscribes you to future notifications on it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343091/documentation-update-february-6th).  As noted in the comments, they can all be managed in [one place now too](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=documentation&sort=watching).

Because such being notified of future changes was so highly demanded, we went ahead and backfilled for everyone who'd edited in the past.

Changing behavior after the fact is always kind of awkward, and you shouldn't have to manually go unsubscribe to a few hundred things just because Discussion took a lot of testing and dev time to get built.  **I'll go ahead and remove your topic subscriptions for you**.

Comment: Thank you, although I'm not sure [this](//stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/108293?filter-tags=python) is non-trivial.

Comment: @RamenChef ah, yeah versions are special cased in a lot of places (especially around review) since they carry a lot of information in what could be very little text.  Makes less sense for future notifications though.  The logic being reused should probably be tweaked a bit, making a note...